# How to get keys and values in dictionary, if key and value is tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have dict `A` and list `B`. Actually keys of A is `x` and `y` which define location, and value of `A` is index of object in `B`.

```
A = {(9, 10): (0, 2, 3), (2, 5): (6, 4, 1), (3, 7): (5, 7, 1)}
B = ['cat', 'fish', 'snack', 'duck', 'mouse', 'pig', 'bird', 'rabbit']
```

I want to print that point `(9,10)` has object in `B`  index `[0]`, `[2]`, `[3]`

```
(9,10) : cat, snack, duck
(2,5)  : bird,mouse,fish
(3,7)  : pig, rabbit,fish
```

Comment: What is the question? Just get the indices and pull the values out of the list. You might find it easier to just store values in the value tuples, though, instead of bothering with the list and index indirection.

Comment: to print the location `(9,0)`, when i use A.keys(0) is error... and i have no idea to get 0 from value `(0, 2, 3)`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using keys? Are you trying to get the 0th element of A? it's a dict, it doesn't really have a well-defined order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a mapping with the index and the corresponding value as a dictionary, like this

```
mapping = {idx: item for idx, item in enumerate(B)}
```

or simply

```
mapping = dict(enumerate(B))
```

then you can simply pick corresponding values from `mapping`, like this

```
for key, values in A.iteritems():
  print("{}: {}".format(key, ", ".join(mapping[value] for value in values)))
```

**Output**

```
(9, 10): cat, snack, duck
(3, 7): pig, rabbit, fish
(2, 5): bird, mouse, fish
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dictionary with the tuple. Then you can generate a new list with the indexes returned.

```
print [B[location] for location in A[(9, 10)]]

# ['cat', 'snack', 'duck']
```